# Ubuntu 16.4 LTS cannot find openjdk-8-jdk

Tags: 16.04, apt, jdk

I had to rebuild a docker container this past week, and as part of a 16.04 container creation, it does an `apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk` which fails with a 404 error.

Switching to `apt-get install default-jdk` tries to pull the same package and, likewise, fails with a 404 error.  See below.  As is normal practice, I run `apt-get update` before trying this.

```
Get:168 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 libxi6 amd64 2:1.7.6-1 [28.6 kB]
Get:169 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 libxrender1 amd64 1:0.9.9-0ubuntu1 [18.5 kB]
Err:170 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 openjdk-8-jre-headless amd64 8u151-b12-0ubuntu0.16.04.2
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.162 80]
Get:171 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 ca-certificates-java all 20160321ubuntu1 [12.5 kB]
Err:170 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 openjdk-8-jre-headless amd64 8u151-b12-0ubuntu0.16.04.2
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.162 80]
```

Did the 16.04 repos get all wonky all of a sudden?

Thanks much!

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get update` before installation again.

Comment: I had the same problem on 17.10. I gave up trying to install JDK8 and just installed JDK9 which seems to be available on 16.04 repos as well.

Comment: Yes, did the apt-get update as a matter of course, and noted in the above posting.  The docker container is supposed to live long after the package is done and is being set-up per vendor recommendation.

Comment: Not working on `ubuntu:bionic` even after `apt-get update`
Error: `E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/o/openjdk-8/openjdk-8-jre-headless_8u222-b10-1ubuntu1~18.04.1_amd64.deb  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.88.31 80]
`

Answer (score 7):

Did you do `sudo apt-get update` recently?  If not, do that, then try again.

The 404 error is that it's hunting a specific version of the package that is not available on the repos anymore, and this usually happens when your repository 'state' information is out of date.  Usually a call to `sudo apt-get update` will fix that problem, and then you can retry the `sudo apt-get install` command you were trying to run again.

Comment: Did that as a matter of course.   Note that trying to install metapackage "default-jdk" ends up with the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Thomas, the repos have been fixed.  Rerunning `sudo apt-get update` now -- I mean, after Thursday, 4/12/2018, resolves the issue.

Thanks much!

Answer (score 0):

I'm on WSL2 and following [these instructions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1096930/sudo-apt-update-error-release-file-is-not-yet-valid) was required to complete the installation.

Apparently the WSL instance was not time-synced with the real host time, causing problems with apt-get update && install.