# Getting 'Release is not valid yet' but time date valid

Tags: dual-boot, apt, updates, debian

i can't use this line:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

or even

```
sudo apt-get -o Acquire::Check-Valid-Until=false update
```

and i get this error

```
Err:1 http://your.repo.domain/repository bionic InRelease
  Could not resolve 'your.repo.domain'
Hit:2 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease                                                  
Hit:3 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                                           
Ign:4 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                                                        
Hit:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease                                               
Get:7 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release [943 B]       
Get:8 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release.gpg [819 B]  
Hit:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease                  
Get:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [109 kB]
Hit:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-proposed InRelease
Hit:12 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Get:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease [109 kB]
Reading package lists... Done                              
E: Release file for http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/Release is not valid yet (invalid for another 1h 1min 1s). Updates for this repository will not be applied.
E: Release file for http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/InRelease is not valid yet (invalid for another 4min 20s). Updates for this repository will not be applied.
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list:1
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list:1
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list:1
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list:1
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list:1
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list:1
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (main/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list:1
W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list:1
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list:1
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list:1
```

I've search on the internet for 2hours trying everythifn with no success
I've even fixed my date time

```
date
```

give me the good time.
I have Ubuntu 18.04 and Windows 10 on dual Boot.

Comment: Check your timezone  (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuTime)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sudo apt update error: "Release file is not yet valid"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1096930/sudo-apt-update-error-release-file-is-not-yet-valid) and [How can I fix apt error “W: Target Packages … is configured multiple times”?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760896/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a workaround for ya:

echo "Acquire::Check-Valid-Until "false";\nAcquire::Check-Date "false";" | cat > /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/10no--check-valid-until

All one line, guaranteed to work