# Installing latest NodeJS on Ubuntu 22.04 via WSL on Windows 11

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, nodejs

I am in Ubuntu 22.04 via WSL on Windows 11.

`curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_18.x | sudo -E bash -`

is returning :

```
## Installing the NodeSource Node.js 18.x repo...

## Populating apt-get cache...

+ apt-get update
Hit:1 https://apt.releases.hashicorp.com jammy InRelease
Hit:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Get:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease [110 kB]
Hit:4 https://packages.redis.io/deb jammy InRelease
Get:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease [119 kB]
Get:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease [107 kB]
Reading package lists... Done
E: Release file for http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-security/InRelease is not valid yet (invalid for another 5h 27min 34s). Updates for this repository will not be applied.
E: Release file for http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-updates/InRelease is not valid yet (invalid for another 5h 27min 59s). Updates for this repository will not be applied.
E: Release file for http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-backports/InRelease is not valid yet (invalid for another 5h 28min 40s). Updates for this repository will not be applied.
Error executing command, exiting
```

```
$ sudo head /var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_jammy_InRelease
-----BEGIN PGP SIGNED MESSAGE-----
Hash: SHA512

Origin: Ubuntu
Label: Ubuntu
Suite: jammy
Version: 22.04
Codename: jammy
Date: Thu, 21 Apr 2022 17:16:08 UTC
Architectures: amd64 arm64 armhf i386 ppc64el riscv64 s390x
```

What am I to do ?

```
$date
Fri Feb 24 04:12:40 IST 2023
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This *looks* like a clock or timezone issue, similar to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/1096930/1165986).

> `Fri Feb 24 04:12:40 IST 2023`

Google tells me that it is currently about 5 pm IST now.  Given the time that you posted this (currently 5 hours ago), it should have been around noon your time?

At this point, the issue may have resolved itself (via a WSL<->Windows clock sync) already, but if not, for WSL, try:

- Confirm that your Windows clock and timezone are correctly set
- In Ubuntu, `sudo hwclock -s`
- Try again

If that doesn't work:

- From PowerShell, `wsl --shutdown`
- Reboot the Windows host
- Try again

Also see [WSL2 Clock is out of sync with Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65086856/11810933) on Stack Overflow for some historical information on this.

Comment: `sudo hwclock -s` solved the problem.